# Axis labels not showing in d3 chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3 and currently trying to create a line graph. The axis are created with the right dimensions, however the label for the axes are not showing up. They are there, as when I highlight where they are supposed to be, they show up. They must be hidden or being displaying with a white fill but I'm not sure as to why that is happening. Below is my code for adding axes to the chart.

```
var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data[0].values, d => d.date))
  .range([0, width1-margin1]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 40])
  .range([height1-margin1, 0]);


/* Add Axis into SVG */
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(10);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(10);

svg1.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height1-margin1})`)
  .call(xAxis);


svg1.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
}
```

The values are there, they are just not displayed for some reason

Comment: Can you make a snippet in the question that reproduces this behavior?

Comment: from the code snippet above its not enough to give you answer. My bet is that your css for 'axis' class is painting text in the same color as background...

Comment: Or the margins are not set large enough